# Where are binary executable files located on Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a simple shell that would use all the available executables. My question is: Where are all the executable files located? I know that one of the folders containing such files is is /usr/bin, but this folder does not contain, let's say, ifconfig program. Is there a complete list of executable files used by, for example, bash?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

> Where are binary executable files located on Linux?

In paths in `PATH`.

Let's take it all, from [posix manual 8.3 Other Environment Variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html#tag_08_03):

> PATH
> This variable shall represent the sequence of path prefixes that certain functions and utilities apply in searching for an executable
> file known only by a filename. The prefixes shall be separated by a
> colon ( ':' ). When a non-zero-length prefix is applied to this
> filename, a slash shall be inserted between the prefix and the
> filename. A zero-length prefix is a legacy feature that indicates the
> current working directory. It appears as two adjacent colons ( "::" ),
> as an initial colon preceding the rest of the list, or as a trailing
> colon following the rest of the list. A strictly conforming
> application shall use an actual pathname (such as .) to represent the
> current working directory in PATH . The list shall be searched from
> beginning to end, applying the filename to each prefix, until an
> executable file with the specified name and appropriate execution
> permissions is found. If the pathname being sought contains a slash,
> the search through the path prefixes shall not be performed. If the
> pathname begins with a slash, the specified path is resolved (see
> Pathname Resolution). If PATH is unset or is set to null, the path
> search is implementation-defined.

See also [shell command search and execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01_01) which calls [execve](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/execve.html).

> Is there a complete list of executable files used by, for example, bash?

I think the following command should work "good enough":

```
( IFS=:; find $PATH -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable )
```

but it doesn't handle the "zero length prefix" and "trailing colon". I think that could be handled with a little `sed` by inserting that missing dot there:

```
( PATH=$(sed 's/^:/.:/; s/::/:.:/g; s/:$/:./' <<<"$PATH"); IFS=:; find $PATH -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable )
```